# Adding a "." to my url's path

Tags: html, url, web

This question may seem a bit off, but rather than having a url path let's say for a mail section such as "mysite.com/mail" how can I make it so that it reads as "mail.google.com" like it does with google mail?

thanks

Comment: That's called a subdomain (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain). It'll be hard to answer without knowing your exact setup. If you search for 'How to add subdomain' here it will show you some results on various languages, etc.

Comment: Thanks very much!